# Kafka Windowed State Stores not cleaning up after retention

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

For some reason my old state stores are not cleaning up after the retention policy is expiring. I am testing it locally so I am just sending a single test message in every 5 minutes or so. I have the retention durations set low just for testing. retentionPeriod = 120, retentionWindowSize = 15 and I assume retain duplicates should be false.  When should that be true?

```
Stores.persistentWindowStore(storeName,
                        Duration.of(retentionPeriod, ChronoUnit.SECONDS),
                        Duration.of(retentionWindowSize, ChronoUnit.SECONDS),
                        false)
```

When I ls in the state store directory I see the old stores well after the retention period has expired.  For example, store.1554238740000 (assuming the number is epoch ms).  I am well pass the 2 minute retention time and that directory is still there.

What am I missing?

Note, it does eventually clean up just a lot later than I was expecting.  What triggers the clean up?

Answer (score 0):

Retention time is a minimum guarantee how long data is stored. To make expiration efficient, so-called segments are used to partition the time-line into "buckets". Only after the time for all data in a segment can be expired, the segment is dropped. By default, Kafka Streams uses 3 segment. Thus for your example with a retention time of 120 seconds, each segment will be 60 seconds big (not 40 seconds). The reason is that the oldest segment can only be deleted of *all* data in it is passed the retention time. If the segment size would only be 40 seconds, 4 segments would be required to achieve this:

```
S1 [0-40) -- S2 [40,80) -- S3 [80,120)
```

If a record with timestamp 121 should be store, S1 cannot be deleted yet, because it contains data for timestamps 1 to 40 that are not passed retention period yet. Thus, a new segment S4 would be required. For segment size 60, 3 segments are sufficient:

```
S1 [0-60) -- S2 [60,120) -- S3 [120,180)
```

For this case, if a record with timestamp 181 arrives, all data in the first segment are passed the retention time of 181 - 120 = 61 and thus S1 can be deleted before S4 is created.

Note, that since Kafka 2.1, the internal mechanism is still the same, however, Kafka Streams enforced the retention period at application level in a strict manner, ie, write are dropped and reads return `null` for all data passed the retention period (even if the data is still there, because the segment is still in use).